# How to reprint the footer for each of the report's pages

Tags: jasper-reports

The `<group>..</group>` tag unfortunately does not provide a boolean `isReprintFooterOnEachPage` attribute similar to the `isReprintHeaderOnEachPage` attribute. Is there a way to reprint the footer for each one of the report's pages please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *"reprint the footer for each one of the report's pages"* or rather to display a page footer in each page you should use the **pageFooter** band

```
<pageFooter>
    <band height="50">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="07a50461-bd56-4060-80eb-cd1a86ac6bdc"/>
            <text><![CDATA["This is the page footer"]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

> **Notes**
>
> - You can have last page with different page footer by adding also the `lastPageFooter` band
> - If you need to have the footer band also displayed on the summary page make sure to set the attribute `isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true"` on the `jasperReport` tag.
> - If you do not like to have page footer on first page use the `title` band and set the attribute `isTitleNewPage="true"` on the `jasperReport` tag

<sup>Answering since the current solution of OP does not seem correct and may create confusion for future users</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your feed-back :)